# calculate the percentage of data that are within the range in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data base like this, but bigger.

```
  Indicea<-c(1,2,3,5,3,1,3,5,3,6,NA,2,1,1,3,2)
  Indiced<-c(0.1,0.5,06,032,0.1,0.25,0.23,0.12,0.15,NA,0.25,0.45,1.0,0.5,0.26,0.45)
Especialidad<-c("gato","gato","gato","perro","perro","perro","perro",
    "buho","buho","buho","buho","tigre","tigre","tigre",NA,"tigre")
Fecha<-c("01/03/2020","02/03/2020","03/03/2020","04/03/2020",
 "05/03/2020","06/03/2020","07/03/2020","08/03/2020",
 "09/03/2020","10/03/2020","11/03/2020","12/03/2020",
 "13/03/2020","14/03/2020","15/03/2020","15/03/2020")
data<-dataframe(Indicea, Indiceb,Indicec,Indiced,Especialidad,Fecha)
```

My ui is perfect And this is a little part of my serve, I have a slideriunput that change acord the column. I need to do a table that group by "Especialidad" and count how many times the selected numbers in the sliderInput appear in the range and the percentage that it represents

```
output$Rango<-renderUI({
   req(input$SeleccioneIndice)
   minn <- min(BD9.3()[,input$SeleccioneIndice], na.rm = TRUE)
   maxx <- max(BD9.3()[,input$SeleccioneIndice], na.rm = TRUE)
   sliderInput("Rango",label = "Seleccione un rango", min = minn, 
   max=maxx, value=c(minn,maxx))
     })
  BD9.5<-reactive({
  BD9.4<-BD9.3()
  BD9.4$Intervalo<-NA
  BD9.4$Intervalo<-replace(BD9.4$Intervalo,BD9.4[,which
    (names(BD9.4)==input$SeleccioneIndice)]>=as.numeric(minn),
        "Correcto")
      BD9.4$Intervalo<-replace(BD9.4$Intervalo,BD9.4[,which
       (names(BD9.4)==input$SeleccioneIndice)]<=as.numeric(maxx), 
        "Fallo") 
 BD9.4$Intervalo<-replace(BD9.4$Intervalo,BD9.4[,which
   (names(BD9.4)==input$SeleccioneIndice )]<=as.numeric(minn),  
       "Correcto")
     BD9.4$Intervalo<-replace(BD9.4$Intervalo,BD9.4[,which
   (names(BD9.4)==input$SeleccioneIndice)]>=as.numeric(maxx),
       "Fallo")

  BD9.6<-as.data.frame(table(BD9.4$specialty.name,BD9.4$Intervalo))
  names(BDa4)<-c("Especialidad","Intervalo","Total")

  BD9.6$Porcentaje<-NA

  for(i in levels(factor(BD9.6$Especialidad))){

    BD9.6[BD9.6$Especialidad==i,]$Porcentaje=round((
    BD9.6[BD9.6$Especialidad==i,]$Total/sum
    (BD9.6[BD9.6$Especialidad==i,]$Total))*100,2)
   }

   BD9.6 <- arrange(BD9.6, Especialidad, Cumplimiento) 
    BD9.6


    output$summary9<-renderPrint({
    BD9.6%>%
   filtro<-subset(BD9.6, Cumplimiento == "Correcto")
    print(arrange(filtro,-Porcentaje))
    })
```

Maybe I am overthinking this, any way, help me please.

Comment: I do not fully follow. It may be simpler to give an example of the calculation that you are trying to do. Then, after solving it, you can apply it to your shiny application.

Comment: Also, I get an error `could not find function "dataframe"`. Did you mean to use `data.frame`  instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should meet your needs.  It may need some adjustment as I am not 100% sure of what your percentage should be.  In the future, please post a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can help you.

```
library(tidyr)

Indicea<-c(1,2,3,5,3,1,3,5,3,6,NA,2,1,1,3,2)
Indiceb<-c(12,15,12,14,13,16,14,13,15,12,14,13,NA,13,11,12)
Indicec<-c(100,NA,120,154,125,201,102,150,102,105,140,156,118,113,175,189)
Especialidad<-c("gato","gato","gato","perro","perro","perro","perro",
                "buho","buho","buho","buho","tigre","tigre","tigre",NA,"tigre")
Indiced<-c(0.1,0.5,0.6,0.32,0.1,0.25,0.23,0.12,0.15,NA,0.25,0.45,1.0,0.5,0.26,0.45)
Fecha<-c("01/03/2020","02/03/2020","03/03/2020","04/03/2020",
         "05/03/2020","06/03/2020","07/03/2020","08/03/2020",
         "09/03/2020","10/03/2020","11/03/2020","12/03/2020",
         "13/03/2020","14/03/2020","15/03/2020","15/03/2020")
data<-data.frame(Indicea, Indiceb,Indicec,Indiced,Especialidad,Fecha)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabItem("IndicesI",
          tabsetPanel(# position= "left",
                      tabPanel("Indices de ingreso", icon = icon("file-medical-alt"),
                               sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput("SeleccioneEspecialidad2"),
                                 uiOutput("SeleccioneIndice"),
                                 uiOutput("Rango"),
                                 uiOutput("RandeDatedI"),
                                 checkboxInput("Todas","Seleccione Todas/Ninguna", value = FALSE)
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 #plotOutput("lineplotI"),
                                 DTOutput("t1"),
                                 DTOutput("summary9")
                               )))
          )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$SeleccioneEspecialidad2<-renderUI({
    choices <- na.omit(data$Especialidad)
    selectInput("SeleccioneEspecialidad2", "Seleccione Especialidad",
                choices=choices, multiple = T, selected = TRUE )
  })

  output$SeleccioneIndice <-renderUI({
    selectInput("SeleccioneIndice", "Seleccione Indice", choices=
                  c("Ments"="Indicea",
                    "Fragilidad"="Indiceb",
                    "ElixhauserAHRQ"="Indicec",
                    "ElixhauserVanWalraven"="Indiced"))

  })

  BD9<-reactive({
    req(input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2)
    data$Fecha <- as.Date(data$Fecha,format= "%d/%m/%y")
    data %>%
      filter(Especialidad %in% input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2 )
  })
  
  BD91<-reactive({
    req(BD9(),input$SeleccioneIndice)
    
    df <- BD9() %>% drop_na(input$SeleccioneIndice, Especialidad)
    df
  })
  output$t11 <- renderDT(datatable(BD91()))
  
  FechaI<-reactive({
    BD9.1<-BD9()
    unique(BD9()$Fecha)
  })

  output$RandeDatedI <-renderUI({
    req(FechaI())
    mymin <- min(FechaI(),na.rm=T)
    mymax <- max(FechaI(),na.rm=T)
    dateRangeInput('dateRangeI',
                   label = 'Seleccione un rango',
                   start = mymin, end = mymax,
                   min = mymin, max = mymax
    )
  })

  BD9.3<-reactive({
    req(input$dateRangeI, BD9())
    BD9.2<-BD9()
    BD9.2 %>%
      filter(Fecha >= input$dateRangeI[1] & Fecha <= input$dateRangeI[2])
  })

  output$Rango<-renderUI({
    req(input$SeleccioneIndice,BD9.3())
    minn <- min(BD9.3()[,input$SeleccioneIndice], na.rm = TRUE)
    maxx <- max(BD9.3()[,input$SeleccioneIndice], na.rm = TRUE)
    sliderInput("Rango",label = "Seleccione un rango", min = minn, max=maxx,
                value=c(minn,maxx))

  })

  BD9.5<-reactive({
    req(BD9.3(),input$SeleccioneIndice,input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2,input$Rango)
    BD9.4<-BD9.3()
    BD9.4 %>%
      filter(.data[[input$SeleccioneIndice]] >= input$Rango[1]  &
             .data[[input$SeleccioneIndice]] <= input$Rango[2]) 
  })
  
  BD96 <- reactive({
    req(BD9.5(),BD91())
    dfsub <- BD9.5() %>% count(Especialidad)
    df1 <- BD91() %>% count(Especialidad) %>% rename(den=n)
    df3 <- dplyr::left_join(dfsub, df1, by=c("Especialidad"),all=TRUE) %>% mutate(Porcentaje = (n/den)*100) %>% select(1,2,4)
    df3
  })
  output$t1 <- renderDT(datatable(BD9.5()))
  
  output$summary9<-renderDT({
    datatable(BD96(), class = 'cell-border stripe', options = list(
      order = list(list(3, 'desc'))))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```